# Redondear a la alta o baja un número

Tags: php

A través del siguiente script:

```
<?php
$fichero = "testFile.txt";
$fichero_w = fopen($fichero, 'w') or die("No se puede abrir el fichero");

$dia_del_ano = date("z")+1;
$fecha_f = $dia_del_ano / 2;
$resultado = 'Dato'.$fecha_f.".ext";
echo $resultado;

fwrite($fichero_w , $resultado);
fclose($fichero_w );
?>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se redondee la diferencia de días entre fechas? Ya que puede dar números como `78.5`, y necesito que sea o `78` o `79`.

Comment: ¿Has probado `$fecha_f = round($dia_del_ano / 2);`? Puedes usar también `int()`, `floor()` o `ceil()` según tus necesidades específicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP dispone de varias funciones para realizar el trabajo que deseas:

- [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval): convierte cualquier dato (cadena, coma flotante, etc) a entero, truncando la parte decimal.

  - `intval(1.9) = 1`
  - `intval(-1.9) = -1`
- [`round()`](http://php.net/round): redondea un número de coma flotante a entero.

  - `round(1.9) = 2`
  - `round(-1.9) = -2`
- [`floor()`](http://php.net/floor): devuelve el valor entero más bajo.

  - `floor(1.9) = 1`
  - `floor(-1.9) = -2`
- [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil): devuelve el entero más alto.

  - `ceil(1.9) = 2`
  - `ceil(-1.9) = -1`

Tu código podría quedar:

```
$fecha_f = round($dia_del_ano / 2);
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que quería con floor y round. Gracias.